# Filter duplicate entrys

Tags: sql

im using this SQL query to get a list of all Azure DevOps Server users with their project and the last access time.

```
Select Object1.DisplayName as 'User Name',
       Object1.SamAccountName as 'R-User',
       Object2.DisplayName as 'Projekt Name',
       StartTime AS Last_Access
From ADObjectMemberships Member1, 
     ADObjects Object1,
     ADObjects Object2,
     tbl_command
Where Object1.ObjectSID = Member1.MemberObjectSID and
      Object2.ObjectSID = Member1.ObjectSID and
      Object1.DisplayName  NOT LIKE '%\%' and
      Object1.DisplayName  NOT LIKE 'APP_%' and
      Object1.DisplayName  NOT LIKE 'CLI_%' and
      Object1.DisplayName  NOT LIKE '%admin%' and
      Object1.DisplayName  NOT LIKE '%svc%'
Order By  'Projekt Name', 'User Name'
```

Sadly i get this result as you can see there is one result for every single acces.

```
Username    User Login  Project     Time
Mustermann, Max RXXXXXX     [FOO]\BAR   2019-10-21 
06:26:26.987
Mustermann, Max RXXXXXX     [FOO]\BAR   2019-10-21 
06:26:26.940
Mustermann, Max RXXXXXX     [FOO]\BAR   2019-10-21 
06:26:26.923
Mustermann, Max RXXXXXX     [FOO]\BAR   2019-10-21 
06:26:26.940
Mustermann, Max RXXXXXX     [FOO]\BAR   2019-10-21 
06:26:26.940
Mustermann, Max RXXXXXX     [FOO]\BAR2  2019-10-21 
06:26:25.937
Mustermann, Max RXXXXXX     [FOO]\BAR2  2019-10-21 
06:26:26.923
Mustermann, Max RXXXXXX     [FOO]\BAR2  2019-10-21 
06:26:27.000
Mustermann, Max RXXXXXX     [FOO]\BAR2  2019-10-21 
06:26:26.327
```

My goal now that i have just one single entry per day per user. When the user is working in multiple projects like in the above example Foo\Bar and Foo\Bar2 i need just one entry per project.

I already tried the DISTINCT command but for me its not working maybe im doing something wrong. Hopefully someone of you could help me :)

**//EDIT 06.11.2019**

Im using this code now and its showing me all users with all projects but also with all access times so i have to filter it for the last (max) time. When i use MAX(StarTime) im getting the same time for every user.

```
USE [Tfs_DefaultCollection]
Select    
Object1.DisplayName as 'User Name',Object1.SamAccountName as 'R-User',
Object2.DisplayName as 'Projekt Name',StartTime AS 'Letzter Zugriff'
From ADObjectMemberships Member1, 
ADObjects Object1,
ADObjects Object2,
tbl_command
Where Object1.ObjectSID = Member1.MemberObjectSID and
Object2.ObjectSID = Member1.ObjectSID and
Object1.DisplayName  NOT LIKE '%\%' and
Object1.DisplayName  NOT LIKE 'APP_%' and
Object1.DisplayName  NOT LIKE 'CLI_%' and
Object1.DisplayName  NOT LIKE '%admin%' and
Object1.DisplayName  NOT LIKE '%svc%'
GROUP By  Object1.DisplayName, Object1.SamAccountName, Object2.DisplayName, StartTime
```

**//EDIT 05.11.2019**

> SELECT TOP (10000000) [PartitionId]
>         ,[CommandId]
>         ,[Application]
>         ,[Command]
>         ,[Status]
>         ,[StartTime]
>         ,[ExecutionTime]
>         ,[IdentityName]
>         ,[IPAddress]
>         ,[UniqueIdentifier]
>         ,[UserAgent]
>         ,[CommandIdentifier]
>         ,[ExecutionCount]
>         ,[TempCorrelationId]
>         ,[AuthenticationType]
>         ,[AgentId]
>         ,[ResponseCode]
>         ,[TimeToFirstPage]
>         ,[DelayTime]   FROM [Tfs_DefaultCollection].[dbo].[tbl_Command]

Thats the structure. In [IdentityName] are the "R-User" -> Object1.SamAccountName as 'R-User' and on "StartTime" we have the last access time

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (**without errors**), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: "I already tried the DISTINCT command but for me its not working" -- Second tip of the day: show us what you tried.

Comment: There's no join condition for the tbl_command table...

Comment: The selected columns don't match the specified result.

Comment: If you want to drop the extra rows, what they would be? Would they be with maximum time or minimum time?

Comment: @nicomp i just tried "select DISTINCT" and the rest was the same. Im not a coder oder SQL guru im happy the basic query is running. I just want to get one results per "User Login" per "Project" and it would be the best if the last "time" is shown

Comment: @AnkitBajpai it doesnt really matter as long as i know if its the maximum or minimum time :)

Comment: @jarlh that tip is twenty years old.

Comment: @Jodrell, and still so many don't know better...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Few notes about your query -

1. User proper explicit join syntax to increase the readability of query.
2. You have used 4 tables but join conditions are only 2. So I guess you are missing 1 join condition.

You may try below query for your desired result -

```
Select Object1.DisplayName as 'User Name',
       Object1.SamAccountName as 'R-User',
       Object2.DisplayName as 'Projekt Name',
       MAX(StartTime) AS Last_Access    --or MIN as per your requirement
From ADObjectMemberships Member1
Join ADObjects Object1 ON Object1.ObjectSID = Member1.MemberObjectSID
Join ADObjects Object2 ON Object2.ObjectSID = Member1.ObjectSID
     --tbl_command You Need a join condition for this table.
Where Object1.DisplayName  NOT LIKE '%\%' and
      Object1.DisplayName  NOT LIKE 'APP_%' and
      Object1.DisplayName  NOT LIKE 'CLI_%' and
      Object1.DisplayName  NOT LIKE '%admin%' and
      Object1.DisplayName  NOT LIKE '%svc%'
Group By Object1.DisplayName,
         Object1.SamAccountName,
         Object2.DisplayName
Order By 'Projekt Name', 'User Name'
```

Comment: Sadly im getting and Error

    Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 7
    Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'JOIN'.

As i said im not a SQL query guy. I will try to fix that error on my own but maybe you could help :) Also dont understand your message regarding the tbl_command

Comment: @Juggybash, Please try now.

Comment: I have edited my first Post. Seems like using (MIN) or (MAX) is giving me same time for every person. The query i edited is working but givin me all times a user acced the git. Cant find the error seems like an unsolvable error for me :D

Comment: If you are using MAX function with StartTime, remove the StartTime from GROUP BY Clause. Having StartTime column in group by clause and with MAX function giving you the same data for every user.

Comment: But using your query and just setting tbl_command without join i get same date/time for all users. My query from the first post is working but giving me multiple times for the same user and project not the maximum (last) time

Comment: Can you share the structure of TBL_COMMAND table?

Comment: Can i share it in my first post ?

Comment: @Juggybash, yes you can.

Comment: I shared it also i will send you a mail if thats ok

Comment: Cant get that working. Sadly didnt get an answer from Ankit

Comment: @Juggybash, I will suggest that you should leave this question here as it is and post a new question with the all tables structures and your desired result from that data.